# Can part of a composite primary key be used as part of a composite primary key on another table?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I am trying to figure out how to create this relationship. It is for employees that participate in an incentive program. They can participate multiple years and also be doing the same job. So it is a many to many relationship. I also need to be able to get the records by the year. So is this the best way? Is is even possible?

**Employee Table:**

```
EmpID PK
Year PK
```

**Job Table:**

```
JobID PK
Year  PK
```

Answer (score 1):

For a many to many relationship, the standard approach is to create a separate table (mysql syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE employee_job
( empl_id integer not null,
  job_id integer not null,
  foreign key (empl_id) references employee(empl_id),
  foreign key (job_id) references job(job_id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store which employee participated in what job for what year, you can have a more simple design:

```
Employee        
--------
EmpID PK

Job
--------
JobID PK

Year (optional)
--------
Year  PK

Participation        
-------------
EmpID PK, FK1
JobID PK, FK2
Year PK, FK3  (the FK3 is optional)
```

---

If you also want to store in separate tables which jobs were active/available which year and which employees were employed which year (if for example you had employees that were employed some years but did not participate in any job or if you have jobs that were available but noone worked in them), you could have the more complex design you are suggesting:

```
Employee        
--------
EmpID PK

Job
--------
JobID PK

Year
--------
Year  PK

Employment
----------
EmpID PK, FK 
Year PK, FK

JobActivity
-----------
JobID PK, FK 
Year PK, FK

Participation        
-------------
EmpID PK, FK1
JobID PK, FK2
Year PK, FK1, FK2
```

The FK1 would reference `Employment(EmpID, Year)` and the FK2 would reference `JobActivity(JobID, Year)`